# Change character based off of its position? Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string on unknown length, contain the characters a-z A-Z 0-9. I need to change each character using their position from Left to Right using a dictionary.

Example:

```
string = "aaaaaaaa"
def shift_char(text):
    for i in len(text):
        # Do Something for each character
    return output
print shift_char(string)
'adktivep'
```

Comment: hey @Austin, how are you describing, which character on which position should convert to which character?

Comment: @TonyMontana that will be set in my program. The idea is to have a dictionary for each position. so if ' f ' is ' 3 ' characters in, look for ' f ' in ' dict3 '. I will be using this to help write a encryption concept i made to code. And yes, i have read why [we shouldn't roll our own encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own). But this is just a personal project for now.

Comment: @TonyMontana of course, thats just my idea of how this would work. If you have a better idea, feel free to speak up.

Comment: How are the dictionaries made? Are they randomised? Or are they shifted? (like a Caesar cipher).

Comment: @bobsterman they are static, but will be randomly generated using a script once i write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433191/convert-int-into-str-while-in-getitem-python-2-7), I was able to come up with a solution. The following example only uses 4 dictionaries, while i intend to do more:

```
# Input String
string = "ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt"

# Defining dictionarys for 0-4
dicnums = [{"0":"n","1":"Q","2":"k","3":"W","4":"F","5":"g","6":"9","7":"e","8":"v","9":"3","a":"r","b":"T","c":"c","d":"o","e":"b","f":"y","g":"2","h":"A","i":"i","j":"p","k":"1","l":"P","m":"w","n":"x","o":"s","p":"Y","q":"h","r":"G","s":"7","t":"S","u":"6","v":"K","w":"Z","x":"M","y":"C","z":"J","A":"u","B":"f","C":"j","D":"E","E":"a","F":"H","G":"O","H":"N","I":"l","J":"U","K":"I","L":"V","M":"m","N":"5","O":"R","P":"4","Q":"z","R":"L","S":"0","T":"q","U":"D","V":"8","W":"B","X":"X","Y":"d","Z":"t"}, {"0":"q","1":"6","2":"W","3":"4","4":"J","5":"u","6":"n","7":"T","8":"I","9":"O","a":"V","b":"3","c":"Z","d":"s","e":"R","f":"E","g":"G","h":"P","i":"5","j":"l","k":"e","l":"m","m":"F","n":"t","o":"8","p":"K","q":"L","r":"Y","s":"M","t":"D","u":"j","v":"z","w":"H","x":"g","y":"9","z":"f","A":"0","B":"p","C":"o","D":"d","E":"X","F":"S","G":"k","H":"1","I":"Q","J":"C","K":"U","L":"i","M":"r","N":"w","O":"y","P":"B","Q":"2","R":"x","S":"A","T":"c","U":"7","V":"h","W":"v","X":"N","Y":"b","Z":"a"}, {"0":"x","1":"W","2":"q","3":"B","4":"j","5":"I","6":"E","7":"g","8":"U","9":"e","a":"8","b":"3","c":"5","d":"k","e":"9","f":"N","g":"7","h":"Q","i":"t","j":"r","k":"L","l":"Z","m":"b","n":"n","o":"Y","p":"H","q":"R","r":"6","s":"P","t":"1","u":"S","v":"M","w":"p","x":"l","y":"F","z":"2","A":"c","B":"T","C":"G","D":"h","E":"X","F":"v","G":"s","H":"O","I":"D","J":"4","K":"a","L":"A","M":"m","N":"d","O":"C","P":"f","Q":"V","R":"i","S":"o","T":"u","U":"w","V":"0","W":"K","X":"z","Y":"y","Z":"J"}, {"0":"x","1":"W","2":"q","3":"B","4":"j","5":"I","6":"E","7":"g","8":"U","9":"e","a":"8","b":"3","c":"5","d":"k","e":"9","f":"N","g":"7","h":"Q","i":"t","j":"r","k":"L","l":"H","m":"b","n":"n","o":"Y","p":"Z","q":"R","r":"6","s":"P","t":"1","u":"S","v":"M","w":"p","x":"l","y":"F","z":"2","A":"c","B":"T","C":"G","D":"h","E":"X","F":"v","G":"s","H":"O","I":"D","J":"4","K":"a","L":"A","M":"m","N":"d","O":"C","P":"f","Q":"V","R":"i","S":"o","T":"u","U":"w","V":"0","W":"K","X":"z","Y":"y","Z":"J"}]

# Changing my string characters
string_fin = ''.join(dicnums[i%4][c] for i,c in enumerate(string))

# Print result
print string_fin
```

The result is `"SD11SD11SD11SD11SD11SD11SD11SD1"` if i use all 't's. If i make the dict range broader, and am not using the same characters repeatedly(which i wont be) then the output would be much better. Once combined with the rest of my encryption concept, my program *might* actually work like i want.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, hopefully this is understandable, otherwise feel free to ask questions.

```
import random
import string

# Letter pool, these are all the possible characters
# you can have in your string
letter_pool = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)

input_string = "HelloWorld"
string_length = len(input_string)

# Generate one random dictionary for each character in string
dictionaries = []

for i in range(string_length):
    # Copy letter_pool to avoid overwriting letter_pool
    keys = list(letter_pool)
    values = list(letter_pool)
    # Randomise values, (keep keys the same)
    random.shuffle(values)

    # This line converts two lists into a dictionary
    scrambled_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))

    # Now each letter (key) maps to a random letter (value)
    dictionaries.append(scrambled_dict)

# Initiate a fresh string to start adding characters to
out_string = ""

# Loop though the loop string, record the current place (index) and character each loop
for index, char in enumerate(input_string):
    # Get the dictionary for this place in the string
    dictionary = dictionaries[i]
    # Get the randomised character from the dictionary
    new_char = dictionary[char]
    # Place the randomised character at the end of the string
    out_string += new_char

# Print out the random string
print(out_string)
```

Edit: If you want to only generate the random dictionaries once, and load them in everytime, you can serialise the `dictionaries` array. My favourite is [json](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html).

Comment: Okay, i took a look at your code, and test-ran it. The output i got was completely random. Not sure if i am doing it wrong, or you miss understood. But either way this is NOT what i want. I need to be able to predictably change the characters so that i can also reverse the change in a different part of the final code. Maybe use a seed to generate the dictionaries?

Comment: Okay, after a farther test i have concluded that this is not what i am looking for. I replaced `input_string = "HelloWorld"` with `input_string = "ttttttttttt"` and in console i got the result "vvvvvvvvvvv". You see, I am trying to scramble repeating characters so that they don't match anymore. But in such a way that i can reverse the outcome later on. Lets say `input_string = "test"`. In "test", t=1 e=2 s=3 t=4 and so on. I need the code to say, "Okay, 't' is in slot '1', so it should be lets say 'Q'. Okay, 't' is also in slot '4', so that should be 'f'." Do you see what i mean?

Comment: Oh whoops, I see. What about strings longer than 36 characters?

Comment: Not sure.. The input string in question can easily be tens of thousands off characters long. I have an idea that you inspired.. So, in reference to my last comment, how "test" was checked by length "1,2,3,4" I am trying to work with limiting the length, and then repeating that limit. I am generating a string that will match the input string in length, but will be specific characters in order(e.g: 0-7. so "HelloWorld" would be "01234567012" based off its length) and then finding and replacing the characters using `num_string[#]` and `input_string[#]` so i can track the current replacement char