# Convert int into str while in __getitem__ Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay, i have this string:

`string = "HelloWorld"`

And for this example, I am using a dictionary similar to this:

`dic = [{'a':'k','b':'i'},{'a':'i','b':'l'},{'a':'x','b':'n'},{'a':'q','b':'o'}]`

Now.. I need to reference a dictionary from the list, so that I can change the characters in my string. To do so normally I would just do this:

`dic[#]`

But in this case I also need a value from that dictionary. Now I tried this:

`dic[int(char[i[letter]])]`

But I get the error:

`'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Searching for the error gives me answers here on StackOverflow, but they do not fix my problem.

Comment: You can't subscript an integer with brackets, `i` is an integer so you can't do `i[string[i]]`

Comment: strings are also immutable, so you can't assign `string[i]`.

Comment: what are you expecting doing such a strange expression `string[i] = dict[int(char[i[string[i]]])]` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest replace character string[i] with a character from one of my dictionaries.

Comment: `dict` is also a builtin class, so you shouldn't use it as a variable name.  I think you want `dict[int(char[i])][string[i]]`, but that is not the best way to do it.  Drop the `char` usage, and use `dict[i%4][string[i]]`.  You still can't assign to `string[i]` though.

Comment: @MarkTolonen it was just for this example. Its actually called "dicnums" in my program

Comment: @mark How can i change the characters of the string then?

Comment: You have to build a new string from the old.  I'd use `join`.  See my attempted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my best crystal ball guess at what you want.  The keys of your dictionary are only `a` and `b`, which aren't any characters in `HelloWorld`, but if you actually had characters from your string as keys like the following, this is how I'd do the replacement, assuming you want to rotate through the four different dictionaries:

```
string = "HelloWorld"
D = [{'H':'a','o':'e','l':'i'},{'e':'b','W':'f','d':'j'},{'l':'c','o':'g'},{'l':'d','r':'h'}]
print ''.join(D[i%4][c] for i,c in enumerate(string))
```

Output:

```
abcdefghij
```

Comment: Question: I had the value "char" so that for every character in the string, a value of 0-3(in my program its actually 0-7)repeating, so that i can change each character differently based off of its position from Left to Right. would the `i%4` accomplish this..? So 'qjsfikeijshlnvdu1le' would be '0123456701234567012'

Comment: `enumerate` generates the index and character of each position in the string.  `i` is the index, `c` is the character.  `i%4` is the remainder of `i/4` so will generate 01230123....  If you want 0-7, use `i%8`.

Comment: You also helped me solve another post with this. So i posted the answer and gave you credit [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39433530/5614171).